# linux command same position show difference thing

Tags: linux, ls

I use command ls in the same position, but show diff things.

```
[tiankonguse /usr/local/services/video_sphinx-1.0]# pwd;ls -a;ls -a ../video_sphinx-1.0/
/usr/local/services/video_sphinx-1.0
.  ..  bin  conf  etc  var
.  ..  conf  etc  incSphinxIndex.sh  indexer  search  searchd  syncCoverToSphinx.py

[tiankonguse /usr/local/services/video_sphinx-1.0]# cd ../video_sphinx-1.0/
[tiankonguse /usr/local/services/video_sphinx-1.0]# pwd;ls -a;ls -a ../video_sphinx-1.0/
/usr/local/services/video_sphinx-1.0
.  ..  bin  conf  etc  var
.  ..  conf  etc  incSphinxIndex.sh  indexer  search  searchd  syncCoverToSphinx.py
```

Comment: Off-topic, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YuHao thanks. move [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168589/linux-command-same-position-show-difference-thing)